# How to mark a vertex has been visited in graph

Tags: c, graph-theory, breadth-first-search, path-finding

I am implementing graph structure for my path finding in a maze program. In some operation like: traversing graph, free the graph (which is malloc-ed before, or use breadth first search,... It is require to check if a vertex is visited or not.

This is `vertex` and `edge` struct:

```
typedef struct graph
{
    // val just use to label the vertex
    int val;

    // since the maze just has 4 directions,
    // I simplify vertex to just point to 4 other vertices
    edge up;
    edge down;
    edge left;
    edge right;
}vertex;

typedef struct Edge
{
    int weight;
    vertex *neighbour;
    bool visited;
}edge;
```

I have thought about 2 solutions. The first is add `bool visited;` in `vertex` or `edge` struct and initialize it to `false`, but it just able to use 1 time, because I don't know how to reinitialize the `visited`. The second approach is make a link list, put the visited vertex in that list and check for visited vertex in that list when required. But it costs so much work when there are hundred of vertices.

So what is the good mechanism to check a vertex is visited? What is the better way to implement this problem?

Comment: Another way, without re-initialising, is to store the iteration count. If the count stored != current iteration value, the node has not been visited.

Comment: Is "iteration count" the same as "val" in `vertex` struct ? @WeatherVane

Comment: No, it would be the same value for every vertex. Suppose you compute one path, the count could be `1`. When you compute the next path, the count can be `2`. Do you see? So long as there are not so many passes of the graph that the counter wraps, it's a convenient solution, and you don't have to run around resetting the vertex status. The idea is to use it as you would a boolean, but only one specific value is considered as 'visited', which you advance for each traverse of the graph (not for each node).

Comment: ...to look at it another way, the node would store the reference number of the most recent traverse that visited it. If it's the current traverse, the node has been visited.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ahh, I get it, this is such a worth considering approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first solution you can add bool visited to edge and vertex, and whenever you visit something you add it to a linked list, so when you are done and you want to re-initialize them to false you make one pass on the linked list and update their values and then clear the linked list.

The other solution is that when you visit a node or an edge you put them in some balanced binary search tree (map, set ... or something that you implement on your own), these allow you to add an element or check for an existence of an element in O(log(n)) where n is the total number of elements.